# Can a browser automatically debug a Javascript function if this function is not having any error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I know that in the browsers we can debug those Javascript functions which are having error but is there any way to debug Javascript function which is not having any error?
For example if I have a javascript function in my button control and this function is not giving any error, so can my browsers automatically debugs(just to check the logic of function) this Javascript function when I click on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good article to JS debugging in Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Open the Scripts tab in your developer tools, find the function, and click the bar on the left side of any line to set a breakpoint.

Comment: I know it but in case if I don't know which function is being used I mean I am not aware about the function name so can my browser automatically start debugging that function?

Comment: Different browsers have different ways of setting event breakpoints.

Comment: Is there any link for the same? I would really appreciate your effort.